# Custom right segue in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, segue

I'm trying to have a right segue from two view controllers and the problem is that when it makes the transition, the first view controller makes the segue but it seems to glitch almost overlap itself for a quick second, and then place the new view controller on it. I have looked at other posts online and nobody seems to have this problem.

```
class UIStoryboardSegueFromRight: UIStoryboardSegue
{
    override func perform() {
        let src = self.source as UIViewController
        let dst = self.destination as UIViewController
        let transition: CATransition = CATransition()
        let timeFunc: CAMediaTimingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        transition.duration = 0.2
        transition.timingFunction = timeFunc
        transition.type = kCATransitionPush
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight

        src.view.window?.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
        src.present(dst, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I have included the route in the images below. The source is using a UINavController that has a root controller that is a TabViewController. That TabViewController is then attached to a UIViewController which is the controller that is making the segue call with the custom transition shown on the very right of the picture.

[All_Feed ViewController which is the source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YY7W.png)

The destination is just a UIViewController shown in the link below.

[Post Page ViewController which is the destination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdIq3.png)

Comment: What do you mean with right segue? Do you mean a push segue?

Comment: It would almost look like the screen is being pushed to the right/left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with this method of transitioning between view controllers. Have you tried using `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontrolleranimatedtransitioning

This would also let you abstract the logic in a more reusable way than doing it inside of a segue.

Since you want the source to present the destination, you would make your destination VC the transitioning delegate in order to hook up UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning logic

Since you haven't shared any visuals I'm not going to try to translate the animation you are trying to accomplish but maybe this tutorial can also help you understand how to implement the transition this way: https://www.objc.io/issues/5-ios7/view-controller-transitions/

Comment: I tried using the UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning and no luck, I just edited the post to show more in detail visuals of my setup

Comment: Is there an animated example online somewhere of the kind of transition you are trying to accomplish?

What do you mean "no luck" with UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? Would love to know more because I believe fairly strongly that this is what you really want to be using. The combination of CATransition with an unanimated present seems a bit odd to me. It looks like you are fighting the framework because modal presentations are built to play nice with UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning

Comment: The UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning actually did help, I just was looking at it the wrong way.